# PHP SEND SMS API

Tags: php, sql, curl, sms

have a look at below snippet inside my PHP code :

```
function SMS(){

$msg1="".$bookingNo."\n".$guestName."\n".$guestEmail."\n".$guestPhone."\n".$guestAddress."\n".$place."\n".$account."\n".$reportingDate."\n".$reportingTime."";   
file('http://sms.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.in/api/webxxxx.php?workingkey=76565xxxxxx&sender=ILUVU&to=9897xxxxxxx&message='.$msg1.'');}
```

The problem is this that this http link is sending SMS successfully when run on browser window, 
with some dummy text in `&message=`.

But when I am assigning all defined and tested variables inside `$msg1` & calling it in same url.

Woosh, it shows NO ERROR & nothing happens, on calling this function. NO SMS.

I wonder where m wrong ?

Thanks

UPDATED CODE :

```
function SMS(){

$bookingNo=$_REQUEST['bookingNo'];
$guestName=$_REQUEST['guestName'];
$guestEmail=$_REQUEST['guestEmail'];
$guestPhone=$_REQUEST['guestPhone'];
$guestAddress=$_REQUEST['guestAddress'];
$place=$_REQUEST['place'];
$account=$_REQUEST['account'];
$reportingDate=$_REQUEST['reportingDate'];
$reportingTime=$_REQUEST['reportingTime'];

$msg1="".$bookingNo."\n".$guestName."\n".$guestEmail."\n".$guestPhone."\n".$guestAddress."\n".$place."\n".$account."\n".$reportingDate."\n".$reportingTime."";
file('http://sms.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.in/api/webxxxx.php?workingkey=76565xxxxxx&sender=ILUVU&to=9897xxxxxxx&message='.$msg1.'');}



}
```

SMStoDriver();

Comment: Try to release your caps lock.

Answer (score 2):

Newline characters are not allowed in URLs. You need to encode the message:

```
function SMS(){

    $bookingNo=$_REQUEST['bookingNo'];
    $guestName=$_REQUEST['guestName'];
    $guestEmail=$_REQUEST['guestEmail'];
    $guestPhone=$_REQUEST['guestPhone'];
    $guestAddress=$_REQUEST['guestAddress'];
    $place=$_REQUEST['place'];
    $account=$_REQUEST['account'];
    $reportingDate=$_REQUEST['reportingDate'];
    $reportingTime=$_REQUEST['reportingTime'];
    $msg1=urlencode("Booking No: $bookingNo\nName: $guestName\n Email: $guestEmail\nPhone: $guestPhone\nAddress: $guestAddress\nPlace: $place\nAccount: $account\nDate: $reportingDate\nTime: $reportingTime");
    file('http://sms.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.in/api/webxxxx.php?workingkey=76565xxxxxx&sender=ILUVU&to=9897xxxxxxx&message='.$msg1.'');}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar. But my issue is that my query is sending me SMS but it contains only few blank lines. Your code is giving me no SMS. This - message='.urlencode($msg1)); sending me SMS with - .urlencode($msg1). Plz help how to get decoded values in my SMS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you setting all the variables `$bookingNo`, `$guestName`, etc.? If they're set outside the function, you either have to pass them as parameters or use a `global` declaration to be able to access the outside variables.

Comment: OK. I made all the used variables local now , declared/ assigned inside this function. Now how to use .urlencode ? but get SMS with decoded message ?

Comment: The sms.xxx.co.in server should automatically decode the URL. This is just part of the standard syntax for URL parameters.

Comment: If it's still not working, please add an update to your question showing the current code.

Comment: &message=urlencode($msg1) or &message=.urlencode($msg1) , both not working, just giving me this code in SMS... :(

Comment: Voila..it worked ! Thanks Tons Barmar. Just little more help. How can I format it like - Booking no: $bookingNo . "\n" ........

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use the `file` method to make the web request. Perhaps your PHP ini is configured to [not allow file I/O requests to URLs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php).

You would be better off making the web request with something like [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://sms.xxxxxxxxxxxxx.co.in/api/webxxxx.php?workingkey=76565xxxxxx&sender=ILUVU&to=9897xxxxxxx&message=test',
    ));

$resp = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```